# jQuery event on anchor tag without hashtag in href attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

This doesn't seem to work:

```
$('a:not([href^="#"])').on('click', function() {
  // ...
});
```

Is it possible to write a jquery selector that can do this?

Answer (score 3):

`^=` will look only at the beginning of the attribute, and so won't filter out `foo.html#hash`. To look *anywhere* in the attribute, use `*=` (more in [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings)):

```
$('a:not([href*="#"])').on('click', function() {
  // ...
});
```